# Animation Nodes Loop Performance

Tags: performance, animation-nodes

I'm using static parameters in **Loop Subprograms**.

[image]

Setting up these parameters let's me modify the node tree easily, but I noticed, that I never change the inputs. I would like to move unnecessary input into the loop subprogram.

[image]

This seems like a bad idea, if an **extra instance** is created each time the loop is run. (I am already having poor performance.)

Does having more instances created inside the loop (versus as input parameters) affect the performance negatively?

An example of how my node setup looks like.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If most of the time is spend in the inner loop there should not be a noticeable performance drop. Also it depends on which nodes you use. If you only use simple nodes like Object Input or Time Info, you should not get any problems.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have updated my question with an example. Which method is more perfomant in that specific (although simplified) case?

Comment: in that case you should definitely use the setup on the right side. The Object Mesh Data node takes longer to execute. (Also in my opinion the right side looks much better.)